# How to force user to make a selection in GtkFileChooserButton

Tags: python, c, gtk, pygtk

I'm using `GtkFileChooserButton` for folder selection. I'm setting the default expected folder by calling `gtk_file_chooser_set_filename` and checking for the result. If the result is false I want to set the selection to something like Null / None / whatever - simply force user to make a selection himself because I have a code to validate it later.

I have already tried several methods like `set_filename`, `select_filename`, `set_current_folder` by passing null or empty string but that either doesn't work (it selects first folder in hierarchy from the previous call which does exist) or fails. Calling unselection also does not seem to work.

Part of my logic clears that folder so I really need user to make the selection if default expected folder does not exist.

I'm actually doing this in Python with PyGtk but I'm happy with any explanation in Gtk and C/C++.

Comment: Why can't you create a temporary folder, set it as the default choice, and check it later?

Comment: Is [`gtk_file_chooser_unselect_all()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-unselect-all) what you're looking for?